# websocket connection inside kubernetes pod drops

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, kubernetes-pod

I am using AWS EKS cluster, K8's version 1.19.
Docker version 20.10.7
Rancher 2.6.1

I have an application with 2 components running inside one pod.  For discussion purposes i will call these backend and notification. (I am not a programer and did not build the applications.  I am a devops engineer trying to get them to work properly)

The backend accepts websocket connections on port 3000.
The notification container does not have any ports open and expects no incoming traffic.  In face it is idle most of the time.  It connects to the backend over localhost:3000 from time to time to check for and trigger notifications.

It is my understanding that a websocket, once created does not close until something closes it.  However, what is happening is that after its been idle for a while, the notification service tries to connect to the backend, but can't.  The backend thinks its already connected using a particular session id.  But the notification server, detects no connection and tries to connect with a new session id. When it can's connect, the notification container will restart.  It will sometimes get into a restart loop and causes the application to be inaccessible with a 503 error.

So the question is why is the websocket connection closing on the backend?  The backend container is not restarting.  The servers are not under a heavy load.  Indeed this seems to happen most often when the backend and notification service are idle.  The application will sometimes run for a few days with no issue.  Then restart multiple times in a two or three hour period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon the implementation of websocket apis for a language /framework to  provide the heartbeat mechanism to check/set ttl for client/server connection.

In your case , you might need to implement that heartbeat mechanism to avoid the sudden termination of connection .

Example: https://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/heartbeats.html#sending-and-receiving-heartbeat-messages

Comment: The developers insist that keep alives are not necessary as  they are built in to websocket.  If the stack is deployed on Docker the problems does not seem to exist.  if the stack is deployed in k8s but each container in a separate pod, the problem does not exist.  But If the containers are in the same pod, the backend seems to close the connection .  The connection is initiated by notification by connecting to locahost:3000.  It creates a session id.  The notification server is pretty idle and doesn't do much for long periods of time.  After some time the backend closes the connection.

Comment: Can you check why the backend container is getting killed . Is there a particular reason as per pod description?

Comment: The backend container does not get killed.  It stays running.  But for some reason the notification container stops being able to talk to it.

Comment: did you configure liveliness probe for the both the containers ?

Comment: No I did not. I don’t use them as a general rule.

Comment: could you please apply them to your containers & see if that make difference . these probe's all purpose is to check contain is alive & restart if needed & to  enable/disable them for traffic (readiness) . Readiness probe can work as heart beat to ensure backend container is able to server traffic .